# Can I assign a variable from another variable without changing its value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to write a dog years calculator using JavaScript. It takes the input age, does the math and outputs a string with the age in dog years. I am having trouble. I can't figure out how to pull the number for the age and do the math without changing the age the user inputs.

```
//Creating a variable with my age
let myAge = 37;
//The first two years of a dog’s life count as 10.5 dog years each. This is the math
let earlyYears = 2;
earlyYears *= 10.5;
//Each year following the first 2 equates to 4 dog years.
let laterYears = myAge -= 2;  //This is the problem line - how can I do this without changing myAge?
laterYears *= 4;
// Combine the two numbers for my age in dog years.
myAgeInDogYears = laterYears + earlyYears;
//Hi, my name is:
let myName = "Dwayne".toLowerCase();

console.log(`My name is ${myName}. I am ${myAge} years old in human years which is ${myAgeInDogYears} years old in dog years.`);
//output is "My name is dwayne. I am 35 years old in human years which is 161 years old in dog years."
```

Is there a way to do the same thing without changing the first variable?
Please keep things simple. I started learning JavaScript 5 days ago. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand it right, but tried you `let laterYears = myAge - 2;`

Comment: Stop using [compound assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) operators? It also helps to declare all of your variables with `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: Do one thing at a time,
first you do ```myAge -= 2;``` and then you do ```let laterYears = myAge;```

Comment: Do you understand what `-=` does? Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @AugustJelemson, they *don't* want to change `myAge`... It looks like a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
let laterYears = myAge -= 2;
```

to

```
let laterYears = myAge - 2;
```

-= means that you want to change myAge variable and then assign it to laterYears

Thanks for letting us help you

Answer (score 1):

`-=` is an assignment operator. You can read more about assignment operators [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp).

`laterYears = myAge -= 2` is same as `laterYears = myAge = myAge - 2` which decrements the value of `myAge` by 2.

So if you don't want to change the value of this variable, I'd suggest replacing:

`laterYears = myAge -= 2` by `laterYears = myAge - 2`.

Good luck learning javascript!